# Laravel - Passing form data to another page to continue form

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I'm having trouble passing form data from one view to another, I don't want to validate the data and insert it into the database. I just need the data so I can insert it into a larger form.

I tried redirecting my post model with the variables from the first part of the form to the full form so I can display the data from the first form.

```
public function postQuote(Request $request)
{
    $fromDest = $request->input('from-dest');
    $toDest = $request->input('to-dest');


    return redirect('/quote')->with('fromDest', $fromDest)
        ->with('toDest', $fromDest);
}
```

But the variable doesn't pass. Is there any other method I can use to simply just pass the data onto another page?

I'm pretty new to Laravel, mostly used to the traditional ways of dealing with forms.

Comment: this is done with a session, you need to save the request to a session and then continue to another page

Comment: Please show us how you are trying to retrieve the variables on the other page.

Comment: @dparoli {{ $fromDest }} <-- Essentially like this

Comment: @lewis4u Really? Thought it would be simpler than that, thanks for clearing it up though.

Comment: its a redirect, the `with()` passes the variables in the session. You have to retrieve them with `session('fromDest')`

Comment: @dparoli Ah! Now I understand, Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must store data in session to use it in the next request

See the docs
[Flash Data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data)

i hope this will help you.